# Read data from an event

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory, scheduled-tasks

I need to setup a Windows Scheduled Task for an event from Active Directory.

The content(I don't know how it's called) of my event is something like:

[image]

Is there a way to read and use the values of account name and Event ID from this event in a batch file which will start when this event occurs ?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html

Answer (score 1):

with [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) you can trigger a batch file with `/sc onevent` :

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONEVENT /mo */EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']='reduser' /EC Security /tn check_event /tr "c:\some.bat"
```

where `/mo ..` is an xpath for the elements you want to pass through your filter.In this case related to the user reduser (as this is a not hidden info in your screenshot)

[with](http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html)

```
wevtutil qe Security wevtutil qe security /q:*/EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']='reduser'
```

you'll list events in the Security related to the `reduser` and the last line will be the last event.And you can get additional filtering by adding the system time in xpath filer - the format is always `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.msZ` - or with piping through findstr . To get the desired time format independently of the settings you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389) .

Though it's a little cumbersome to parse the xml line with pure batch and get the things you want - the line is too long and you might need two embedded for loops to parse the data. Her[e](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/ProcessesUtils/startHidden.bat) I've event log data with wevtutil to get a info about started process , so I suppose you can use it as a reference.